# Tabularx with \hline and overrightarrow vertical spacing

Tags: math-mode, tabularx, vector

I use a `\overrightarrow` in my tabularx table with `\hline`. Howover, the vector arrow is mixed with the line. Is there a **good** way to fix this error other than manually putting spacing ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|Y|}\hline
a&$\overrightarrow{\mathrm{AB}}$&c\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative with the `cellspace` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|SY|Y|}\hline
a & $\overrightarrow{\mathrm{AB}}$ & cdeffg \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{<more space between rows>}` (or with the @Zarko'definition *stretchering factor*), to increase the space of the cells for example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|Y|}\hline
a&$\overrightarrow{\mathrm{AB}}$&c\\\hline
\end{tabularx}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is not `vertical distance` but stretchering factor :-)  (now I can't remember its  official name). +1!

Comment: @Zarko I have invented the definition italian->english language ;-).-)

Answer (score 4):

Another possibilities is to use `\makegapedcells` from `makecell` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

{
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|Y|Y|Y|}\hline
a & $\overrightarrow{\mathrm{AB}}$ & cdeffg \\\hline
\end{tabularx}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]